# How to use Word styles across documents

Tags: osx-yosemite, styles, microsoft-word-2008

I have Microsoft Word for Mac 2008 and I use a Macbook (Yosemite).

I have a paper written in Word (let’s call it document A) and I need to format it according to some formatting guidelines. I have a Word document from the conference organizers (B) which is formatted according to these guidelines. B can be used as a template, it contains all the styles the conference wants (for headings, abstract etc.).

Now, the smart thing would have been to write my paper A using B as a template since the beginning. But I have not done that. So now I am trying to use the styles from B in A. I have found this challenging. Any tips?

I have tried:

I) copy chunks of text from A into B. This works sometimes but not always as sometimes the text from A does not format according to B as desired.

II) save B as a template and save the styles in B. Open A, set the template of A to B and look for those styles. In this way, I can go to e.g. each heading and format it according to the heading style from B. Still, this does not always work smoothly.

What I find frustrating is my inability to define a set of styles from one document and being able to access them easily from the other document.